# twitter bootstrap - glyphicon is not fitting properly inside anchor tag (IE 11 issue)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to include glyphicon inside an anchor tag and it is not fitting correctly when the page is resized (IE 11 issue). The html is given below,

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a>
                 Results Count
                <span class="badge"></span>               
                <a href="#" id="LinkAgenda" class="col-xs-offset-1">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i>
                        Download Agenda
                </a>
            </h4> 
        </div>
</div>
```

when the page is resized, the glyphicon is not moving along with the text. See the snapshot below,

[image]

**Fiddler:** https://jsfiddle.net/ebwwvy6m/22/

Any suggestion to fix this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This may have nothing to do with the behavior, but why is the HTML element for `glyphicon-info-sign` an `<i>`, but the element for `glyphicon-download` is a `<span>`?

Comment: @DrewWills, good catch. Just to keep the code in consistent, I replaced span with <i>. Anyhow, still the same behavior.

Comment: You shouldnt use the col-xs class in an anchor.

Comment: @user1655756, is there any reason? I want to have consistent space between Records Count and Download Agenda. The same code is working fine in chrome...

Comment: Well, cols go inside a row. Plus you are using a col when you just want to have a left margin. If you want them to be cols then surround the whole thing with a row and put a div col around Result Count and Download Agenda.